Conda environment stuck on solving environment in google colab
I'm trying to follow installation here on google colab, with some minor modifications such as using condalab to install conda with my notebook. However, I'm running into an issue where when I run this command:
conda env create -f environment.yml && conda activate cpc37

It stalls at solving environment. As in the, loading wheel just stops in place and the cell will run past 20 min without any update. I'm looking at this solution currently but I've found nothing about this issue specifically relating to google colab. Does anyone have any advice on what to do?
Update: Yes, so the fix with priority channels did not work for me. Also, I made conda verbose, and the environment command seems to be stalling at the solving step here:

I'm not incredibly well versed in conda so I can't really figure out why this is happening. But hopefully this is useful information to someone.
Update 2: This seems to indicate that colab struggles with tdqm. I'm looking into how I could address this potentially.
